# I have a error in my godot script gdscript can you please solve it

Tags: godot

```
onready var healthBar : TextureProgress = get_node("HealthBar")

func update_health_bar (curHp, maxHp):
  
    healthBar.max_value = maxHp
    healthBar.value = curHp
```

Error is: Invalid set index 'max_value' (on base: 'Nil') with value of type 'int'.

Answer (score 0):

your healthBar was null when you called `update_health_bar`.

This might be because you don't have a children node called "HealthBar" or it is not a `TextureProgress` node.

Can you send a screenshot of your scene tree ?

It should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter such an error, it usually is because I am instancing the scene dynamically via scripts, and to get around the `null` error I create a init function to assign the node.

So in your case, after instancing your scene and adding it to the scene tree, call init on your scene, where you init function is as follows:

```
func init():
    healthBar=get_node("HealthBar")
```

Maybe that might work.